# How can I make clusters of time frame?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a Pandas Dataframe of Time.

```
0    2020-08-01 23:59:59
1    2020-08-01 23:59:49
2    2020-08-01 20:52:17
3    2020-08-01 19:02:34
4    2020-08-01 18:38:06
```

I want to add a column where I want to index by making a cluster. For eg. as follows:

```
0    2020-08-01 23:59:59   1
1    2020-08-01 23:59:49   1
2    2020-08-01 20:52:17   2
3    2020-08-01 19:02:34   3
4    2020-08-01 18:38:06   3
```

I have written this for this example as we can see 3 clusters can be made, which are the nearest/closest time stamps.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
mat = df['datetime'].values
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
kmeans.fit(mat.iloc[:,1:])
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(mat.iloc[:,1:])

df['cluster'] = y_kmeans
```

However, the above code also didn't work. Well, I have millions of data and obviously don't know how many clusters should I need to make. I read Elbow Method can be used but not exactly sure how it can be done. Can someone direct how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

`kmeans` assumes that you know the number of clusters.

If you want a method that determines the number of clusters algorithmically, you can e.g. use [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) which forms a cluster whenever a group of data points is "close" to each other (closeness determined by the `eps` parameter). If you have a large number of samples and this is very costly, you can also try to explore any clusters in the data using a smaller (representative) subset of the data.

Comment: DBSCAN will output random number of clusters depending on params you feed to it

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I wouldn't say "random", but yes, based on ``eps`` and ``min_samples``.

Comment: There are 64+ different methods to define an "optimal" num of clusters. It is a responsibility of data analyst to determine num of clusters based on business logic, interpretability, reproducibility and any other relevant factor. Algo is not a substitue to business logic.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov DBSCAN is an established clustering algorithm that has its use among the other 63. Of course, you're right that the use case determines the choice,  though I've never claimed otherwise so I'm not sure what you're arguing for or against. So if you want to add something to the answer or provide one of your own, I would kindly suggest you to do so.